# Can't Figure Out Encoding for Beautiful Soup Object

Tags: python, encoding

I've been trying to print out text of this site with Beautiful Soup:
http://www3.forbes.com/entrepreneurs/25-most-expensive-schools-worth-every-penny/26/

Using `lxml` to parse the site returns gibberish and strange characters and other parsers wouldn't return anything at all. I've tried specifying the encoding as UTF-8 to match the site`<meta charset="UTF-8">` , but have had no luck. What would be the correct parser to use, and how would I implement it?  I'm a beginner with Beautiful Soup and would really appreciate a simple , clear explanation. Thanks!

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

URL = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www3.forbes.com/entrepreneurs/25-most-expensive-schools-worth-every-penny").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(URL,'xml')

print(soup.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing gibberish not because of BeautifulSoup or string encodings, but because of urllib and the *content*-encoding of the server. The respone headers from the server include this:

> Content-Encoding: gzip

Usually by default if the *Accept-encoding* header sent to the server when retrieveing an url is left empty, the server should *not* compress the content. For some reason however, the server you are accessing does not care about this and sends it gzipped aynway. Even if the headers are explicitly set to `'Accept-encoding': 'identity'` like this:

```
URL = urllib.request.Request("http://www3.forbes.com/entrepreneurs/25-most-expensive-schools-worth-every-penny")
URL.add_header('accept-encoding','identity')
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
```

You can of course try to decompress the gzipped response with python by yourself (it is possbile), but your best option here is to use some other library (if you can) for retrieving the url, like `requests`. You can install `requests` with pip from command line:

```
pip3 install requests
```

And then retrieving the URL in your code:

```
import requests

URL = requests.get("http://www3.forbes.com/entrepreneurs/25-most-expensive-schools-worth-every-penny/26/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(URL.text,'lxml')

print(soup.text)
```

That will output some javascript code with it though, not just the text from the site.

You *can* use selenium too, like the other answer suggests. However, selenium is meant more for situations when you need to actually execute javascript in the site, or interact with it like you would by using a browser. So if you only need to retrieve some static text, urllib or requests is the thing you want to use, it will be more lightweight.

Comment: In addition to this nice, insightful answer the OA might be interested in the document, https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/urllib2.html.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a year and half trying to figure out encoding in beautiful soup, without finding any correct answer. 
I dropped away this library when I discovered selenium and selenium.webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver   = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id("<tag id>")
```

It is just a delight : http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/